# Unable to connect Bluetooth fitness tracker with google fit sdk

Tags: android, google-fit, google-fit-sdk

Every time i got no result found
also added failure listener to it but it never called

```
GoogleSignInAccount googleSigninAccount =GoogleSignIn.getLastSignedInAccount(this);
    int timeoutSecs = 12;
    List<DataType> list = Arrays.asList(DataType.TYPE_STEP_COUNT_DELTA);
    BleScanCallback bleScanCallbacks = new BleScanCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onDeviceFound(BleDevice device) {
            // A device that provides the requested data types is available
            tev.setText("Device found with: "+device.getName());
        }
        @Override
        public void onScanStopped() {
            // The scan timed out or was interrupted
            tev.setText("Nothing Found");
            pb.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
    };
    Task<Void> response = Fitness
            .getBleClient(this, googleSigninAccount)
            .startBleScan(list, timeoutSecs, bleScanCallbacks );
    response.addOnFailureListener(mFailureListener);
}
```

Comment: Can you elaborate on "no result found". Does that mean you are not getting any callbacks?

Comment: BleScanCallback called after 12 seconds but onDeviceFound() never called every time it calls onScanStopped() so i got the message of nothing found

Comment: I'm not sure what error you are facing, but to help you understand well about bluetooth, try to visit the documentation on [how to use bluetooth sensors](https://developers.google.com/fit/android/ble-sensors). From there, you will find sample codes as reference. Also, keep your software up to date as well as the apps. Then, check for any firmware update for your bluetooth. To see detailed steps, check [this blog](https://thewirecutter.com/blog/understanding-bluetooth-pairing-problems/).

Comment: Well thanks but i have according to the official documentation but not able to search my device

Comment: Hi @MuhammadAqeel did you found the answer?

Comment: @VadimEksler not yet

Comment: you get this `onScanStopped`?

Comment: yes `onScanStopped` called after the timeout

Comment: what is your sensor? what brand and model?

Comment: brand is fitbit and model is charge 2